# Django logs user in by default

Tags: python, django

I have a Django account, where there is only one user for the entire app. I also have not setup admin for this app.

The problem is, when I first start my docker container for the Django app and type in my domain, I am **already logged in**. Even if I open this in a private window or another browser (Firefox; I normally use Chrome), the issue still remains.

This is the script to create the user:

```py
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
import os

# Create user and save to the database
if User.objects.exists():
  print("user already exists")
else:
  username = os.environ.get("USER_USERNAME")
  email = os.environ.get("USER_EMAIL")
  password = os.environ.get("USER_PASSWORD")

  if not username or not email or not password:
    print("user information not supplied. please check your .env that USER_USERNAME, USER_EMAIL, USER_PASSWORD are all set.")
  User.objects.create_user(username, email, password)
  print("created user")
```

This is called from `docker-compose.yml` like this:

```yaml
services:
  web:
    build: .
    
    command: >
      bash -c "mkdir -p static
      && python manage.py collectstatic --no-input
      && python manage.py migrate
      && python manage.py shell < init/create_user.py
      && $$RUN_SERVER_COMMAND"
```

Why does this happen? Is there a setting to turn off "logged in by default"?

Comment: How do you know that you are logged in? What response do you get, what do you expect and can you add the relevant code/template?

Answer (score 0):

I realized that this happened because I was returning the same layout for the top page for both logged in and logged out users. In both cases I was showing "click here to login".